# Javascript stops working after deploying to Heroku

Tags: javascript, html, css, heroku

When I run my code locally, my Javascript works perfectly. But after I deploy to Heroku, none of it works anymore. Why is that?

**Javascript: (file called basic.js)**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 700) {
        $('nav').addClass('shrink');
    } 
    else {
        $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
    } 
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-contents">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact-us">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#customer-quote">WHAT WE DO</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#showcase-section">SHOWCASE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about-section">ABOUT US</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="basic.js"></script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mainNav.shrink {
    background-color: darkgray;
    transition: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition:  0.8s;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the page console? What about heroku logs? Can we see the structure of your server file?

Comment: Can you open your developer tools and see in the Sources tab whether the javascript was loaded at all?